# Query using generics

Tags: java

Write using generics the below code.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateSession();
CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Item> cr = cb.createQuery(Item.class);
Root<Item> root = cr.from(Item.class);
cr.select(root);

Query<Item> query = session.createQuery(cr);
List<Item> results = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basic solution:

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> clazz){    
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateSession();
        CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<T> cr = cb.createQuery(clazz);
        Root<T> root = cr.from(clazz);
        cr.select(root);

        Query<T> query = session.createQuery(cr);
        List<T> results = query.getResultList();
        return results;
    }
```

and you can call the function as:

```
List<Item> items= findAll(Item.class);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfect. I had another query, appended the question, can you please let me know if that's possible? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Very welcome. Regarding your new question, normally such internal variables should not be extracted to be class attributes. Could you please tell more why you want them to be declared outside the function?

Comment: I need to invoke the above api several time's, so isn't it better if i can have them as "private static" in a class and reuse the same? instead of creating one on each function call.

Comment: absolutely no, that way is not thread-safe, and your code will break unexpectedly. So it's better to keep it as is.